# ASPX Gridview - Stretch Datacell over multiple rows

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview in my APSX that looks like below:

[image]

I want to be able to stretch the 'Comments' data cells so they stretch to the bottom of each section (stretch an extra 3 cells down)

I have tried numerous things and nothing seems to be working for me, I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction to do this.

This is the code I am using for my Gridview..

```
...
  <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="20%" HeaderText="Project Name">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="ProjectNameLab" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[Project Name]")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="20%" HeaderText="Customer Name" SortExpression="Customer Name">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="CustomerNameLab" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[Customer Name]")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="10%" HeaderText="Month" SortExpression="Month">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="MonthLab" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Month")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="10%" HeaderText="App Date" SortExpression="ApplicationDate">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="ApplicationDateLab" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ApplicationDate")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="12%" HeaderText="Value" SortExpression="ThisApp">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="ThisAppLab" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ThisApp")%>'></asp:LinkButton>
                                <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server"
                                    Enabled="True" PopupControlID="EditPopup1" TargetControlID="ThisAppLab"
                                    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
                                </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="20%" HeaderText="Comments" SortExpression="Comments">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="CommentsLab" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Comments")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>


                        <asp:TemplateField Visible="true">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="5">
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label Style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px" Width="100%" ID="PaidLbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Paid")%>'></asp:Label>
                                            <itemstyle width="100%" />
                                        </td>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="5"></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label Style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px" Width="100%" ID="DifferenceLbl" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                        <itemstyle width="100%" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="5"></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label Style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px" Width="100%" ID="DateFP" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date")%>'></asp:Label>
                                        <itemstyle width="100%" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="5"></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label Style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; visibility: hidden" Width="100%" ID="BlankRowLbl" Text="Blank" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                        <itemstyle width="100%" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>


                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated, Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within your template field you should add a table and set the row span to the amount of rows that you want. Something like :

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="20%" HeaderText="Comments" SortExpression="Comments">
     <ItemTemplate>
           <table>
               <tr>
                   <td rowspan="3">
                       <asp:Label ID="CommentsLab" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Comments")%>'></asp:Label>
                   </td>
               </tr>
           </table>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

EDIT: Try putting the cell in the other template field as another column instead of its own template field.